# Soundcloud e is null

Tags: api, widget, soundcloud

I'm using the client side javascript SDK to connect to soundcloud.
now i want to block all latest tracks in a widget.
if i'm using SC.Widget('frameid') i'll get an error: Widget is not a function
so i have to implement the second script (widget api)

Whether I load the script directly from soundcloud or download it 
I get the error: `e is null`

I tried to load the sdk before the widget api
and I also tried to load the api in document.ready but I still get the same error.
For selecting the iframe I tried to get it via ID and document.getElementbyId(..)
but that still did not work

Can someone tell me the solution?
what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: pls create a fiddle or share the code, afaik u dont need the sc sdk for the widget api

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nwH8A/112/ :S

Comment: your fiddle does not load jquery, thats why you will see in the console: $ is not defined, which tracks / urls / profiles you would like to show? this url: https://soundcloud.com/barehouse_1 ? hello to berlin ;-) before asking again, take a look in the docs here https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget

Comment: my error: e is null in the widget-api, read my comments :)

Comment: your fiddle does not reference jquery and the widget api itself - there is a spelling error as well, compare with: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/9g1b0jzf/

Comment: ok and you can't say anything about the error i get? why throughs the widget-api from soundcloud the error: "e is null" ??

Comment: i dont get this error - according to your fiddle, which acts as basis to help you. beside that - refer to the docs: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api - here is an excellent example to getting started with the widget api.

Comment: ok you dont unterstand my problem. on the developer page about the widget-api there is a link to "this script" ... to use SC.Widget on the global scope. and if i include THIS SCRIPT i'll get the error. see my fiddle code, it use .load(url, callback) to get latest tracks from barehouse_1 ... the problem is that the script from soundcloud throughs the error ...

Comment: sure, i fully understand you. but what do you load, is this a url? on top try to compare the div id with the javascript code - you will see you are missing a d. and in order to help you, please make the fiddle which creates the error you are talking about. otherwise this does not make sense. thank you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nwH8A/114/
i also tried "https://soundcloud.com/barehouse_1" as url for .load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you dont reference the scripts in a proper way.

I hope this sketch points you in the right direction:

JS

```
(function() {
    var iframe2 = document.querySelector('#widget2');
    var widget2 = SC.Widget(iframe2);
    var newurl = 'http://soundcloud.com/bnzlovesyou';

    widget2.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
    alert('ready');
    widget2.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function(eventData) {
        alert('Playing..');
    });
    widget2.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE, function(eventData) {
        alert('PAUSE..');
    });
});

$( "#changetrack" ).click(function() {
 widget2.load(newurl);
});    

}());
```

HTML

```
<iframe id="widget2" width="100%" src = 'http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://soundcloud.com/barehouse_1'>
</iframe>
<div id="changetrack">Change Track / URL to my account ;)</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/wpe2zmLh/

Comment: ok thanks it works just if i add the src to the iframe.
thank you for the bindings.